# django, to render bar and pie charts?

Tags: django, charts

What is the best recommended library to be used for charting solutions coupled with django?
It should be handy to create charts on the fly, with data on server, similar to google analytics. 
Though the [official django website tells](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Charts)  reportlab, just wanted to know what is the most widely used in the market.

PS: I do not want to use google charts API.

Comment: If you want it to be created client-side through JavaScript, your question is not Django-related. It is quite trivial to render data for such libraries both in JSON and in an HTML template. Just go and find your favorite JavaScript library and no need for any Django apps to complicate things. Most of your work will probably be about styling your charts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bars:

```
<meter style="width:75%;height:25px;" id="bars" title="Awesomeness" max="10" low="1" high="8" optimum="5" value="7">Value can be here too</meter>
```

Pie:

```
.pie {
position:absolute;
width:200px;
height:200px;
clip:rect(0px,100px,200px,0px);
-moz-border-radius:100px;
-webkit-border-radius:100px;
border-radius:100px;
}
```

And SVG can also be used too, JS can move things and CSS can add effects.

Comment: Please, can you link to some samples?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/juancarlospaco/Ukk9Q/ is all i can do right now, im at work :P its a Bar at 75% and a Pie at 50%, i use something like that with Bottle and Django built-in Templates

Comment: Now with more time i have done an Example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/juancarlospaco/Ukk9Q/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of javascript charting frameworks. They do most of what you want. But it is javascript.

If you want rendered images: use matplotlib. It can do everything. It is very very very elaborate. You can customize everything. The defaults are pretty OK.

It can do things like showing bar charts for only the data in every April in the last 10 years - without having 11-month-gaps in the graph. Just to give you an example.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Google Charts API, it's relatively simple to use compared to most other options: 
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Charts-Grid](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/charts/) on [Django Packages](http://djangopackages.com/) (which should give you an rough idea which packages are popular in the community) i'd take a closer look at [django-chartit](https://github.com/pgollakota/django-chartit).